Why are A paper sizes rounded to whole millimetres?
A (ISO 216) paper sizes have aspect ratio √2, which means that the sides have to be irrational numbers in millimetres. But the specification rounds the lengths to whole millimetres.
Why is that? The standard specifies tolerances at least 1.5 mm, which means that who is limited to whole millimetres can stay within the specification even if the precise dimensions are irrational. The rounding of the basic dimensions seems pointless and removes the property that A‹x+1› is exactly a half of A‹x› on which the sizes are based.

This isnt really a graphic design issue. Its a manufacturing/engineering issue. Its a bit hard to come by measuring equipment that is qualified to work on irrational numbers. And all the cheap equipment is geared towards millimeter dimensions. So it is prudent to define it to nearest mm, this causes less legal problems in cases of manufacturing disputes.

@joojaa although not a design question, your comment looks like a good answer to it

My idea is that staying within the specified tolerance would avoid legal problems with tools working with whole millimetres, and having irrational dimensions would allow setting tools more precisely if they can work with tens or hundreds of millimetres.

@matj1 well yes but when you would have to have a more expensive Q and A equipment. Its fine to define more digit precision but its a bit difficult to measure. Mainly no irrational numbers because you would need a entirely separate metronomy. This would be astronomically expensive. In practice you are not allowed to specify an irrational numbers because it would be a nightmare if you ever needed to go to a court of law. See the entire point is that there will be cases near the edge now you would need to determine how close to the tolerance limit you are.

Its possible to order hundreds of tons of paper if all of it is wrong size it can get expensive fast. Also you cant assume all error is around the center of your nominal dimension.

Am I right that A sizes are only/mainly used for paper sizes? In which cases would it be beneficial to aim for a higher precision than whole millimeters? It wouldn't be visible to the human eye. Bookbinders hate decimals in my experience. If you make a multipaneled folder where the width of each panel has decimals, they might round to nearest mm which adds up and becomes a problem. It's better to avoid that. Even though their equipment might have 1/100 mm precision they think it's stupid because of the inherent inaccuracy.

Note that the lengths aren't just rounded. A0 is a diagon with an area of 1 m² where the lengths are rounded to nearest mm. The short sides of the subsequent formats are made by taking the long side of the previous format, halving it and flooring the result. The long side is of course just the short side of the previous format.

Because it's not possible to be more precise. A cut is not zero-width.
